# Sending Values from View To ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I have a senario here... (Extremely sorry writing such a long post)

I have are TreeView(Bound to the observable collection of Phones(Different types)) i have a contentCOntrol whose COntent Binding is set to the selectedItem for TreeView

Code....

```
 <Border Grid.Column="2">
            <ContentControl Name="userControlContentControl"
                            Content="{Binding ElementName=PhoneTreeViewUserControl,
                                              Path=SelectedItem,
                                              Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=rightDisplayConverter}}">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityLayer:Settings}">
                        <ViewLayer:SettingsView />
                    </DataTemplate>                       
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityLayer:CandyBarPhones}">
                        <ViewLayer:CandyBarPhonesListView />
                    </DataTemplate>                        
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityLayer:CandyBarPhone}">
                        <ViewLayer:CandyBarPhoneView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityLayer:QwertyPhones}">
                        <ViewLayer:QwertyPhonesListView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EntityLayer:QuertyPhone}">
                        <ViewLayer:QuertyPhoneView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                                       </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>
```

Problem is that when i select a Phone from TreeView(a specific View is populated from contentcontrol) I wish to pass UniqueId(PhoneBase has that Property) to my ViewModel of View and also fire a function in viewModel  so that it can get Data from BusinessLayer... and Initialize the ViewModel and all its Properties.

CodeBehind for UserControl

## region class - QuertyPhoneView

```
/// <summary>
///   Interaction logic for ProductIdEditorView.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class QuertyPhoneView : BaseUserControl
{
    QertyPhoneViewModel quertyPhoneViewModel;
    #region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public ProductIdEditorView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        quertyPhoneViewModel =
            new quertyPhoneViewModel ();
        this.DataContext = quertyPhoneViewModel;
    }

    # endregion
}

#endregion
```

Also in ViewModel I have Messenger Registrations .... but Every time i selected another phone type and then select the former type the messenger are registered again without deregistering Earlier... (I dont have any Deregister method in Messenger, using Marlon's Mediator V2) and its making application Very Slow if used for an 15-20 min  or so

ViewModel for a Typical View..

## region class - QuertyPhoneViewModel

```
/// <summary>
///   QuertyPhoneViewModel
/// </summary>
public class QuertyPhoneViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    # region Member Variables

    /// <summary>
    ///   quertyPhoneDetails
    /// </summary>
    private QuertyPhone quertyPhoneDetails;

    /// <summary>
    ///   oldQuertyPhoneDetails
    /// </summary>
    private ProductId oldQuertyPhoneDetails;

    /// <summary>
    ///   productIds
    /// </summary>
    private QuertyPhones quertyPhones;

    /// <summary>
    ///   productIdModel
    /// </summary>
    private readonly QuertyPhoneModal quertyPhoneModal;

    /// <summary>
    ///   log
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ILog log =
        LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (QuertyPhoneViewModel));

    /// <summary>
    ///   selectedCalTblName
    /// </summary>
    private CalibrationTable selectedCalTblName;

    # endregion

    # region Constructor

    /// <summary>
    ///   QuertyPhoneViewModel
    /// </summary>
    public QuertyPhoneViewModel()
    {
        RegisterForMessage();
        quertyPhoneModal= new QuertyPhoneModal();
        if (QuertyPhoneDetails == null)
        {
            //Requesting TreeViewUsersontrol To send Details
           // I wish to remove these registrations
            Messenger.NotifyColleagues<ProductId>(
                MessengerMessages.SEND_SELECTED_PHONE, QuertyPhoneDetails);
        }
        CancelPhoneDetailsChangeCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelQuertyPhoneDetailsChanges,
                                               obj => this.IsDirty);
        SavePhoneDetailsChangeCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveQuertyPhoneDetailsToTree,
                                                CanSaveQuertyPhoneDetailsToTree);
    }

    # endregion

    # region Properties

    /// <summary>
    ///   CalibrationTblNameList
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<CalibrationTable> CalibrationTblNameList { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   CancelPhoneDetailsChangeCommand
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand CancelPhoneDetailsChangeCommand { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   SavePhoneDetailsChangeCommand
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand SavePhoneDetailsChangeCommand { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///   QuertyPhoneDetails
    /// </summary>
    public ProductId QuertyPhoneDetails
    {
        get { return quertyPhoneDetails; }
        set
        {
            quertyPhoneDetails = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuertyPhoneDetails");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   SelectedCalTblName
    /// </summary>
    public CalibrationTable SelectedCalTblName
    {
        get { return selectedCalTblName; }
        set
        {
            selectedCalTblName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedCalTblName");
            if (selectedCalTblName != null)
            {
                QuertyPhoneDetails.CalibrationTableId =
                    selectedCalTblName.UniqueId;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   QuertyPhones
    /// </summary>
    public QuertyPhones QuertyPhones
    {
        get { return productIds; }
        set
        {
            productIds = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QuertyPhones");
        }
    }

    # endregion

    # region Public Methods

    # endregion

    # region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///   RegisterForMessage
    ///  I wish to remove these registrations too
    /// </summary>
    private void RegisterForMessage()
    {
        log.Debug("RegisterForMessage" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        Messenger.Register(MessengerMessages.RECIEVE_SELECTED_PHONE,
                           (Action<ProductId>) (o =>
                                                    {
                                                        if (o != null)
                                                        {
                                                            QuertyPhoneDetails
                                                                =
                                                                o.Clone() as
                                                                ProductId;
                                                            AttachChangeEvents
                                                                ();
                                                            oldQuertyPhoneDetails
                                                                = o;
                                                            SetCalibrationTables
                                                                ();
                                                        }
                                                    }));
        Messenger.Register(MessengerMessages.REFRESH_PHONEDETILAS,
                           (Action<string>)
                           (o =>
                                {
                                    GetOldQuertyPhoneDetails(o);
                                    this.IsDirty = false;
                                }));
        log.Debug("RegisterForMessage" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   CanSaveQuertyPhoneDetailsToTree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CanSaveQuertyPhoneDetailsToTree(object obj)
    {
        return this.IsDirty && ValidateQuertyPhoneDetails();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   SaveQuertyPhoneDetailsToTree
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "obj"></param>
    private void SaveQuertyPhoneDetailsToTree(object obj)
    {
        log.Debug("SaveQuertyPhoneDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        if (Utility.IsStringNullOrEmpty(QuertyPhoneDetails.CalibrationTableId))
        {
            MessageBoxResult result =
                ShowMessageDialog(
                    "Calibration Table name is not set.Do you wish to proceed?",
                    "Save ProductId",
                    MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                    MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveDetails();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SaveDetails();
        }
        log.Debug("SaveQuertyPhoneDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   SaveDetails
    /// </summary>
    private void SaveDetails()
    {
        log.Debug("SaveDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        if (productIdModel.SaveQuertyPhoneDetails(QuertyPhoneDetails))
        {
            UpdateProgressbarStatus(
                "ProductId " + QuertyPhoneDetails.Specs
                + " saved successfully.",
                false);
            this.IsDirty = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessageDialog(
                "ProductId " + QuertyPhoneDetails.Specs +
                " not saved successfully.",
                "Save ProductId",
                MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error);
            UpdateProgressbarStatus(
                "ProductId " + QuertyPhoneDetails.Specs
                + " not saved successfully.",
                false);
        }
        log.Debug("SaveDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   SetCalibrationTables
    /// </summary>
    private void SetCalibrationTables()
    {
        log.Debug("SetCalibrationTables" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        CalibrationTblNameList =
            productIdModel.FileData.CalibrationTables.CalibrationTableList;
        SelectedCalTblName = (CalibrationTblNameList.Where(
            calibrationTable =>
            calibrationTable.UniqueId.Equals(
                QuertyPhoneDetails.CalibrationTableId))).FirstOrDefault();
        log.Debug("SetCalibrationTables" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   CancelQuertyPhoneDetailsChanges
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "obj"></param>
    private void CancelQuertyPhoneDetailsChanges(object obj)
    {
        log.Debug("CancelQuertyPhoneDetailsChanges" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        GetOldQuertyPhoneDetails(QuertyPhoneDetails.Specs);
        this.IsDirty = false;
        productIdModel.SelectMainProductList();
        Messenger.NotifyColleagues<bool>(
            MessengerMessages.POP_UP_CLOSE_REQUEST, true);
        log.Debug("CancelQuertyPhoneDetailsChanges" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   GetOldQuertyPhoneDetails
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name = "idNumber"></param>
    private void GetOldQuertyPhoneDetails(string idNumber)
    {
        log.Debug("GetOldQuertyPhoneDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(idNumber))
        {
            ProductId tempQuertyPhoneDetails =
                productIdModel.GetProduct(idNumber).Clone() as ProductId;
            if (tempQuertyPhoneDetails != null)
            {
                QuertyPhoneDetails = tempQuertyPhoneDetails;
                QuertyPhoneDetails.Reset();
            }
            AttachChangeEvents();
        }
        log.Debug("GetOldQuertyPhoneDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   AttachChangeEvents
    /// </summary>
    private void AttachChangeEvents()
    {
        log.Debug("AttachChangeEvents" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        QuertyPhoneDetails.Reset();
        QuertyPhoneDetails.PropertyChanged -= OnQuertyPhoneDetailsChanged;

        QuertyPhoneDetails.PropertyChanged += OnQuertyPhoneDetailsChanged;

        log.Debug("AttachChangeEvents" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
    }

    private void OnQuertyPhoneDetailsChanged(object sender,
                                           PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (QuertyPhoneDetails.Changes.Count > 0)
        {
            OnItemDataChanged(sender, e, QuertyPhoneDetails.Changes.Count);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   ValidateQuertyPhoneDetails
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool ValidateQuertyPhoneDetails()
    {
        log.Debug("ValidateQuertyPhoneDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_ENTERED_LOG);
        if (
            !Utility.IsValidAlphanumeric(
                QuertyPhoneDetails.ControllerInformation)
            ||
            (!Utility.IsValidAlphanumeric(QuertyPhoneDetails.PhoneId))
            || (!Utility.IsValidAlphanumeric(QuertyPhoneDetails.Specs)))
        {
            QuertyPhoneDetails.ErrorMsg =
                AddTreeNodeViewModel.ERROR_NO_ALPHANUMERIC;
            return false;
        }
        QuertyPhoneDetails.ErrorMsg = string.Empty;
        log.Debug("ValidateQuertyPhoneDetails" + BaseModel.FUNCTION_EXIT_LOG);
        return true;
    }

    # endregion
}

#endregion
```

I am absolutly Puzzled what to do...
ANy help in this regrad would be GR8!!! Thanks

Comment: Did anybody get the problem... ??

Comment: Do You want to select an item from a treeview (where items inherite from the base class 'CalibrationTable') and show the selected item in a border, and depending of which type the selected item actually is, show it with a special view (specified by datatemplate)? Am I correct? By the way what does the converter in the border's ContentControl binding do?

Comment: @erikH Thanks for looking into it... ill explain you the problmem again... When i select an item in TreeView the Contentcontrol displays the Specific View but the Views ViewModel dont know which "Phone" to display as "UniqueId"(EnitityBase) property of Phone(Selected in TreeView) is Required to give a value to the ViewModel)... I am Currently doing this using Messenger i.e(as you can see in ViewModels Constructor) I request(from PhonesViewModel) to TreeViewModel to give me the Selected Phone and the TreeViewModel Sends It....

Comment: I am looking for a way so that i can send UniqueId from TreeView to the SpecificViewModel with out Using Messengers as its getting the application Slow...(They are registered again and again).

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your ParentViewModel track the SelectedItem instead of having your View do it? I personally hate doing any kind of business logic in my View. It should just be a pretty layer that sits on top of my ViewModels to make it easier for the user to interact with them.

For example, your PhonesViewModel might have:

```
// Leaving out get/set method details for simplicity
Observable<QuertyPhone> Phones { get; set; }
QuertyPhone SelectedPhone { get; set; }

ICommand SaveSelectedPhoneCommand { get; }
ICommand CancelSelectedPhoneCommand { get; }
```

Your View would simply look something like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPhone}" />

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
        <Button Content="{Binding CancelCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPhone} />
</DockPanel>
```

I would leave the validation in your `QuertyPhone` model, but would move the data access to the ViewModel. In my opinion, your models should just be dumb data objects. You also only have to register for messaging in a single place (your ViewModel), and if you  need to do anything when the SelectedPhone changes, simply do it in the PropertyChanged event.

As a side note, I forget if you can bind a TreeView's SelectedItem or not, but if not you can either use a ListBox styled to look like a TreeView, or in the past I've added `IsSelected` properties to my TreeView data objects, and bound the `TreeViewItem.IsSelected` property to that.

Comment: TreeViewUserControl has its own ViewModel and mainView has its own and all the other Usersontrol (which are in DataTemplates) have their own ViewModel. TreeView doesnot have `SelectedItem` property I have managed to some how get selectedItem to my `TreeViewUserControlViewModel` but still how will i be able to pass the `SelectedItem` from TreeViewUserControl ViewModel to OtherUserControl ViewModels (Those in DataTemplates)....

Comment: That's why I use a `ParentViewModel`. Think of your application as your ViewModels only, without using the View for anything other than a pretty UI. If your main form contains a `TreeViewUserControl` and a `MainViewUserControl`, then your `ParentViewModel` should contain the ViewModels for both those objects. The `ParentViewModel` can then subscribe to a `PropertyChanged` event on the `TreeViewModel.SelectedItem`, and can either broadcast the change to interested view models, or can update the viewmodels itself such as setting `MainViewModel.CurrentItem = TreeViewModel.SelectedItem`